# tick axis getting out of svg barchart

Tags: recharts

I am trying to do a barchart with Recharts but ticks on both axis are getting out of svg:

[image]

Do you know to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, your tick labels have an angle that puts them out of the svg zone. To turn back your tick labels like on a line, you need to either update  the `angle` prop to `0`, like the following:

```
<XAxis dataKey="name" angle={0} />
```

Removing the `angle` prop from the XAxis would work as well, since its default value is `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I knew that. My question was actually is there a way to keep the ticks into the global svg whatever the conditions ?

Comment: I meant can the svg grow up to include all the ticks and the chart ?